# Getting "Unable to open the guest session" error

Tags: sql-server, session, desktop-application

I have a desktop application with DBMS sql server 2008 configured in a network.
I can access to the database through SQL Server Management Studio from the computer in the network. But the application does not work on the same computer. Modifying the configuration file didn't help either. I'm always getting the error "Unable to open the guest session.".

Note: I'm on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your application is running on the same network but is unable to connect to SQL Server 2008? If yes, could you please tell us from what application you are trying to connect to SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Improved language.

Comment: Is this an application you are writing the code of? If so let's share some code that you use to connect to your db and we can try to troubleshoot what's going on. Otherwise you should be looking into the documentation of the application you are trying to use on how to configure it correctly.